# Why do people use (*, *::before , *::after) instead of (*, ::before, ::after) for box-sizing in css?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I do not understand why the universal selector is used before the pseudo-elements.

(*,  *::before , *::after)
This is what I've become accustomed to seeing in standard code.

(*,  ::before,  ::after)
Upon trying this version, all the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements still recieve the applied styles, which is what I would expect. I have been using the first method because it's what I was taught but is there anything wrong with the second method?

Comment: Dunno why. For clarity, maybe? Habit? It is redundant, though... I leave a `*` out when it's optional.

Comment: _IMO_ `*::before` is more clear than `::before`. After some refactoring `*, ::before` may become `* ::before` and that is not the same